# Component rerendering count is incorrect while using useRef in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am following a tutorial from the web for learning `useRef` Hook, which works mostly fine except it is unable to print 2 though after that it behaves normally. Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

In the example code, I want to count the re-render of a component using `useRef`. Now if you type something in the input box you will notice it won't render **2** rest all numbers it will print.

**Code -**

```js
const InputField = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");
  const comRef = useRef(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    comRef.current = comRef.current + 1;
  });

  return (
    <div className="fieldset-input-textbox">
      <input type="text" value={val} onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)} />
      <div className="">
        This Component rendered {comRef.current}
        {`${comRef.current > 1 ? " times" : " time"}`}.
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputField;
```

Code Sandbox Link - https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-paper-f2qdhs?file=/src/InputField.js:54-542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your root component wrapped in [`<React.StrictMode>`](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode), so during development, React will render the component twice for the initial mount to help catch accidental impurities.

This causes the effect to be run twice, so `comRef.current` becomes `3` after the component is mounted. Changing refs does not cause rerenders, so this new value is not shown until typing in the text field, which updates the `val` state. Then, it will display `3` and the next effect will run after that.

Comment: After removing the StrictMode, its working fine..though I have a doubt, if it renders twice at the initial mount it should have shown `2` at the first place instead of `1` ?

Comment: @Nesh React discards one of the renders, but it's not specified which one. You should not try to rely on this behavior anyway.